# React HOC error using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm trying to make a wrapper function to make React context consumers a HOC, written in TypeScript. This is what I have so far:

```
import { ComponentType, ConsumerProps, createElement } from 'react';

type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

export const createConsumer = <S>(
  consumer: ComponentType<ConsumerProps<S>>
) => <P>(
  component: ComponentType<P & S>
) => (
  props: Omit<P, keyof S>
) => createElement(consumer, {
  children: (state: S) => createElement(component, {
    ...props as any,
    ...state as any
  })
});
```

It all works fine, except when nesting the HOCs. When I do, it only picks up the props of the last HOC and ignores all others.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createContext } from 'react';

import { createConsumer } from './createConsumer';

const firstContext = createContext({ first: 'value' });
const withFirst = createConsumer(firstContext.Consumer);

const secondContext = createContext({ second: 'value' });
const withSecond = createConsumer(secondContext.Consumer);

const Component = withFirst(withSecond(({ first, second }) => (
//                                        ^^^^^
// TS2459: Type '{ second: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; }' has no property 'first' and no string index signature.
  <div/>
)));
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer in the hopes that someone will come up with a better solution. For this to work the compiler will infer based on return type,it will infer the generic parameter to `withSecond` based on what `withFirst` expects, similarly it will infer the generic parameter to `withFirst` based on what the expected return type for that is but that is where the chain breaks since it would need to infer `Component` now. To get this to work, just add an explicit type to `Component`: `const Component: React.ComponentType<{}> = withFirst(withSecond(({ first, second}) => (<div/>)));`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the reply! I tried what you suggested, but sadly that didn't fix it. In the end I made a some kind of compose function which fixes the types.